# Question about an equation on bagging in Elements of Statistical Learning book

Tags: machine-learning, bagging

This should be a simple question but I must have missed something.

Equation (8.52) of Section 8.7 Bagging on page 285 of Trevor Hastie, *The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction* is equivalent to
$$\mathbf E_{\mathcal P}[(Y-f_{\text{ag}}(x))(\hat{f^*}-f_{\text{ag}}(x))]=0$$
wehre $f_{\text{ag}}(x):=\mathbf E_{\mathcal P}\hat{f^*}$. I do not see the rationale of this equation. Could someone shed some light on the above equation?